# vb.net xml de-serialization returns empty list

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-parsing

I am  trying to deserialize a simple xml that looks like this

```xml
<categories>
    <category name="camera">
        <tags>
            <tag name="6" value="stdy_cam"/>
            <tag name="7" value="shaky"/>
        </tags>
    </category>
    <category name="classify">
        <tags></tags>
    </category>
</categories>
```

This is my load method -

```vb
Private Sub loadAllCategories()
    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer
    Using stream As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\temp\tags2.xml", IO.FileMode.Open)
        serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Category)), New XmlRootAttribute("categories"))
        Me.Categories = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(stream), List(Of Category))
    End Using
End Sub
```

These are my classes -

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class Category
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlArrayItem("tag")>
    Public Property Tags As New List(Of Tag)
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Tag
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlAttribute("value")>
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Everything seems to be ok, but when I run the program the list of Categories is always empty. The program doesn't throw any errors or exceptions. When I debug, it just shows 0 as count for Categories. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getting zero in the list because your class is named `Category` and your element is `category`, lower case *c*. Try this out:

```
<XmlType(TypeName:="category")>
Public Class Category
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlArrayItem("tag")>
    Public Property Tags As New List(Of Tag)
End Class
```

You can also drop the serializable attribute.

**Edit** Fixed up the Tags as well:

```
<XmlType(TypeName:="category")>
Public Class Category
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlArray("tags")>
    Public Property Tags As New List(Of Tag)
End Class

<XmlType(TypeName:="tag")>
Public Class Tag
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlAttribute("value")>
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Comment: That sort of worked, but not completely - I can see that there are categories now, but the tag list is empty in all categories! I tried your advice with Tag class as well - <Serializable(), XmlType(TypeName:="tag")>, but no luck.

Comment: ah! that worked. Thanks a ton. So, the trick was to use XMLArray instead of XMLArrayItem?

Comment: @Jay Yup the property is named `Tags` not `tags`, same issue as before. Darn that case sensitivity.